# Is there any way to have ontology reasoner in Apache Marmotta?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology, protege, apache-marmotta

Is there any way to have a reasoner (such as HermiT in Protege) to check ontology consistency and inferences in marmotta? Or is there a way to generate rules for sKWRL reasoner from ontology file?

Answer (score 1):

Protégé has a plugin for HermiT and other reasoners also support it (FaCT++, Pellet). What is the connection in your question to Apache Marmotta?

Comment: I rephrased the question. Is there a way to use something similar to HermiT in Marmotta, or is there a way to generate/extract SWRL rules (which are implied in the ontology) from an ontology file directly?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could plug-in any reasoner that provides a Sesame interface.